# How to access devices that are on shared network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, router

So I’m sharing my Mac’s Wi-Fi connection through Ethernet, into a router.

I have a few devices hooked up to the router, but mostly it’s the two Raspberry Pi’s that I’m worried about since I SSH into them often. The Pi’s are both connected to the Internet, but I can’t seem to SSH into them from my Mac.

Do I need to be using a different IP address, or is this just not possible?

Comment: If the router is doing network address translation (which the Mac should be handling on its own), then you'll need to set up port forwarding on the router. This is the same any time you try to connect from upstream of the router, whether that upstream is a random device on the Internet or the very device plugged into the router's upstream port.

Answer (score 0):

The Mac's shared connection won't be on the same subnet as the main router.

The Mac is likely to be sharing from 192.168.2.x by default, and will also be doing its own NAT.
If you try to get round that by opening up your subnet mask, you are then going to have 2 DHCP servers fighting each other & still have double NAT.

The solution might be to use something like [IPNetRouterX](http://www.sustworks.com/site/prod_ipnrx_overview.html) to set the Mac up in Bridging mode.

If you're feeling brave, there is a method here to enable bridging, which is so far above my pay grade I'm not even going to try to précis it...
[Bridging a wireless and an ethernet network with OS X 10.8, updated again](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/weblog/2013/bridging_a_wireless_and_an_eth.html)

Or save all the trouble by hanging a WiFi Access Point off the router & use that instead of the Mac's connection sharing.